# solve the system of equation for $a,b,c,d,e$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetric-polynomials

Solve the system of equation for $a,b,c,d,e$

$$3a=(b+c+d)^3$$  $$3b=(c+d+e)^3$$  $$3c=(d+e+a)^3$$  $$3d=(e+a+b)^3$$ $$3e=(a+b+c)^3$$
I try this problem

I find this system of equation is symmetric

i.e, if (a,b,c,d,e) satisfy this system , then it's permutation is also satisfy this equation

I want a problem solving tip to start this problem

Comment: If you can prove that the symmetry of the equations implies that $a=b=c=d=e$, then the first equation becomes $3a = 27a^3$, or $9a^2=1$ when $a\ne 0$.

Comment: How did you prove the symmetry of the system? It is clear that a *cyclic* permutation preserves the equations, but why an *arbitrary* permutation?

Comment: One or more equations (a system) is well defined when it is given the set  to which the unknowns must belong. With your problem is it $\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They cannot have different values.

- Suppose for example $a > c$:

  - then $(b+c+d)^3 > (d+e+a)^3$ so $b+c+d>d+e+a$ and $b-e>a-c>0$ requiring $b>e$;
  - but that needs $(c+d+e)^3 > (a+b+c)^3$ requiring $d > a$;
  - and continuing $e >c$
  - then $b>d$
  - then $c>a$ contrary to the original supposition
- Similarly $c <a$ would lead to $a < c$, reversing the inequalities in the previous point

So $a=c$ and applying this cyclically $a=c=e=b=d$.

We are reduced to solving $3a=(3a)^3$, i.e. $(3a)(3a-1)(3a+1)=0$, giving the solutions $$a=b=c=d=e=0 \text{ or } \frac13\text{ or }-\frac13$$  These three sets of solutions all work with the original equations